# Optimization and cancelation of derivatives

Tags: calculus, optimization

Consider the following program
\begin{align}
\max_{x,y} F(x,y) \quad \text{ s.t. } g(x,y) = 0.
\end{align}
Form lagrarian
\begin{align}
L(x,y,\lambda) = F(x,y) + \lambda g(x,y)
\end{align}

FOCs read
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial F}{\partial x} + \lambda \frac{\partial g}{\partial x} = 0 \Leftrightarrow -\lambda =  \frac{\partial F}{\partial x}\left[\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}\right]^{-1}
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial F}{\partial y} + \lambda \frac{\partial g}{\partial y} = 0 \Leftrightarrow -\lambda = \frac{\partial F}{\partial y}\left[\frac{\partial g}{\partial y}\right]^{-1}
\end{align}

Equalize those
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}\left[\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}\right]^{-1} = \frac{\partial F}{\partial y}\left[\frac{\partial g}{\partial y}\right]^{-1} \Leftrightarrow \frac{\partial F}{\partial g} = \frac{\partial F}{\partial g}. 
\end{align}

- Am I allowed to do that? Is there a theorem to justify the manipulation?

Comment: If $x, y$ are scalars, does $\frac{\partial x}{\partial g}$ or $\frac{\partial y}{\partial g}$ make sense?

Comment: You also need the equation $\frac{\partial L}{\partial \lambda}  = g(x,y) = 0$. The solution $(x,y)$ must satisfy the constraint $g(x,y) = 0$.

Comment: @measure_theory You're right about the scalars. So I've written it properly now.

Comment: @arthur Sure, but the third condition didn't seem to be important here?!

Comment: $\partial F / \partial g$ makes no sense, as $F$ need not be a function of $g$. If it is, $F$ would be constant on the set $\{ g = 0\}$...